# Android saving the audio files into internal storage

Tags: android, audio, storage

Currently I  have created the audio-recording Android App. The file is saved at External Storage.

What if I change the method to save as Internal Storage with the context of MODE_PRIVATE

I have read the Android developers about saving files but I have no idea how to convert the file instance into the byte array to save the file and load the audio file

the below is my code to save the audio file

```
public void onClick(View view) throws Exception {
    if (count == 0) {

        tbxRecordStatus.setText("Record");
        btnRecord.setText("Stop Record");

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Starts",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dateInString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(
                new Date()).toString();
        String fileName = "TVSSSSD_" + dateInString + " record.3gp";

        SDCardpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        myDataPath = new File(SDCardpath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/.My Recordings");

        // mydir = context.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!myDataPath.exists())
            myDataPath.mkdir();


        audiofile = new File(myDataPath + "/" + fileName);

        Log.d("path", myDataPath.getAbsolutePath());
        // File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, fileName);
        // audiofile = fileWithinMyDir;
        // FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());

        recorder.prepare();

        recorder.start();

        count++;

    } else {

        tbxRecordStatus.setText("Stop");
        btnRecord.setText("Start Record");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Recording Stops",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;

        } else {
            tbxRecordStatus.setText("Warning!");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Record First",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

the below is my code to load the audio file

```
recordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File(directory + "/My Recordings");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        recordList.add(list[i].getName());
    }

    Collections.sort(recordList, Collections.reverseOrder());

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            recordList);


    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String fullPathAudio = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + product;

            File resultFile = new File(fullPathAudio);

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(resultFile), "audio/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getFilesDir()`

```
 SDCardpath = getFilesDir();
        myDataPath = new File(SDCardpath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/.My Recordings");

        // mydir = context.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!myDataPath.exists())
            myDataPath.mkdir();


        audiofile = new File(myDataPath + "/" + fileName);
```

For more see [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: how to open the media load back the audio files if we save that as /data/data/mypackage instead of the external storage ?

Comment: If you store audio in internal file use your own media player to play audio See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html  OTHERWISE implement a content provider if you want to share it with other app via intent

Comment: I don't understand how this code actually _saves_ the file to storage. Could someone please explain it a bit? How do we get audio into memory and how do we save it as a file?