# How to store an audio recording into internal storage in android

Tags: java, android

I did this in external storage but can't figure it out when it comes to the internal storage of android phone.

Comment: Go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352081/android-saving-the-audio-files-into-internal-storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352081/android-saving-the-audio-files-into-internal-storage)

Comment: y u want to store in internal storage ..Your application will fail in device like Lenovo A269 which has internal memory of only 12 mb..like this there are many devices

Answer (score 1):

Use App Storage Directory using getFilesDir() as:

```
SDCardpath = getFilesDir();
        myDataPath = new File(SDCardpath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/.My Recordings");

        // mydir = context.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!myDataPath.exists())
            myDataPath.mkdir();


        audiofile = new File(myDataPath + "/" + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android Developer guide contains a section on using internal storage. You can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).