# My soundboard app can't share .mp3 files

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Java and Android programming and I'm working on a soundboard app.
By the moment the app plays a sound when you click on a button, but I also want to add a sharing functionality for every sound (using OnLongClick), but I just can't make it work. 
I've been looking for a solution through the Internet for the past two days but there's no way I can solve it.

I'm using shareIntent, and when the user long clicks the button it will display a list of apps you can share the sound (dropbox, bluetooth, whatsapp...).
If I select dropbox, it just uploads a file with no extension, and sharing with Whatsapp won't work and will display this error: "Failed to send, please try again".

My code looks like this:

```
            final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.sound01, R.id.sound02, R.id.sound03,
            R.id.sound04, R.id.sound05, R.id.sound06,
            R.id.sound07, R.id.sound08, R.id.sound09,
            R.id.sound10, R.id.sound11, R.id.sound12 };

            final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.sound01, R.raw.sound02, R.raw.sound03,
            R.raw.sound04, R.raw.sound05, R.raw.sound06,
            R.raw.sound07, R.raw.sound08, R.raw.sound09,
            R.raw.sound10, R.raw.sound11, R.raw.sound12 };

View.OnLongClickListener listener2 = new View.OnLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++)
            {
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i])
                {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];

                    // Can't share audio. It shares it with no format, so whatsapp won't accept it
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.guillefix.zombie_soundboard/" + selectedSoundId));

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send to:"));
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Intent Filter in Manifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Yes It won't. I just remembered that you cannot send any Image or Audio Directly to WhatsApp. In your case, You will first have to save that audio to your Internal Storage as a **File** and then send that file to WhatsApp
Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352081/android-saving-the-audio-files-into-internal-storage) It will help you.